# Censoring / Highlighting using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a small sample application for highlighting / censoring of a textarea using JavaScript. To start with I'm just trying to replace the letters, though once that is solved my plan was to use mark.js to mark censored words. Right now when I run my application I'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read property 'value' of null on line 21.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Syntax Highlighting</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form name="badwords" method="post" action="" >
  <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
 <br />
 <input id="formSub" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
 </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var div = document.getElementById('formSub'); 

 function replaceWords(event) {
 //Prevent form submission to server 
 event.preventDefault();
 var commentContent = document.getElementById('comments');
 var badWords = ["x", "y", "z"];
 var censored = censore(commentContent.value, badWords);
}   

function censore(string, filters) {
// "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global "|" for OR match
var regex = new RegExp(filters.join("|"), "gi");
return string.replace(regex, function (match) {
    //replace each letter with a star
    var stars = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        stars += '*';
    }
    return stars;
});
}

div.addEventListener('click',replaceWords); 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You look by ID, yet gave only `name` attribute.

Comment: Your script is outside of the `body` tag.  The *only* tags permitted as immediate children of the `html` tag are `body` and `head`.

Comment: Can you please try to find some less offensive example words? You could even use some made up words ...

Comment: @raina77ow That makes sense, thank you

Comment: @Amy I was having issues earlier with Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null and I assumed it was a DOMloading error, and mistakenly thought that would fix it. Thank you for the heads up will correct

Comment: @DavidPostill My bad, I apologize.

Comment: I fixed the missing ID attribute mentioned by @raina77ow and have moved the script to a seperate .js called in the header but now I'm having this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at banned.js:24

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Syntax Highlighting</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form name="badwords" method="post" action="" >
  <textarea id="pesho" name="comments" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
 <br />
 <input id="formSub" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
 </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var div = document.getElementById('formSub'); 

 function replaceWords(event) {
 //Prevent form submission to server 
 event.preventDefault();
 var commentContent = document.getElementById('pesho');
 var badWords = ["crap", "fuck", "cunt"];
   console.log(commentContent.value)
   commentContent.value =censore(commentContent.value, badWords); 
}   

function censore(string, filters) {
    console.log('in')
// "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global "|" for OR match
var regex = new RegExp(filters.join("|"), "gi");
return string.replace(regex, function (match) {
    //replace each letter with a star
    var stars = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        stars += '*';
    }
    return stars;
});
}

div.addEventListener('click',replaceWords); 
</script>
</html>
```

As some of the other guys before me mentioned, you were not targeting the id of the text area but the name attribute, beside that for the function to make actual changes on the view you must change the targeted element value (see the modified example)